# How to skip a dependency when installing a Perl module using cpanp?

Tags: perl, archlinux

I have the following error when trying to install `Apache::Singleton` with `cpanp`:

```
# cpanp i Apache::Singleton
Installing Apache::Singleton (0.15)
Running [/usr/bin/perl -e use strict; BEGIN { my $old = select STDERR; $|++; select $old; $|++; $0 = shift(@ARGV); my $rv = do($0); die $@ if $@; } /root/.cpanplus/5.20.0/build/Apache-Singleton-0.15/Makefile.PL]...
[   info] generating script t/TEST
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Apache::Singleton
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
[MSG] Module 'Apache::Singleton' depends on 'Apache::Test', may need to build a 'CPANPLUS::Dist::Arch' package for it as well
[MSG] Module 'Apache::Singleton' depends on 'ExtUtils::MakeMaker', may need to build a 'CPANPLUS::Dist::Arch' package for it as well
[MSG] Module 'Apache::Singleton' depends on 'Test::More', may need to build a 'CPANPLUS::Dist::Arch' package for it as well
[MSG] Module 'Apache::Singleton' depends on 'mod_perl2', may need to build a 'CPANPLUS::Dist::Arch' package for it as well
==> Making package: perl-apache-singleton 0.15-1 (Wed Jun  4 22:32:47 FET 2014)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Missing dependencies:
  -> perl-apache-test>=1.35
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Missing dependencies:
  -> perl-apache-test>=0
==> ERROR: Could not resolve all dependencies.
```

But `Apache::Test` is already installed with the `mod_perl` package. I can verify this using `perl -e 'use Apache::Test'`. How can I tell `cpanp` to skip this dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you can't skip dependencies, just tests

```
cpanp i ... --skiptest
```

an alternative way of installing the "easy way" could be [`cpanm`](http://p3rl.org/App%3a%3acpanminus), where you have a

```
cpanm ... --skip-installed
```

At least you could always just download the `.deb` file (or `.rpm`/`.tgz`, depending on your distro) and just extract it and extract the `data.tgz` (in `.deb` files, at least) to `/`.

Comment: I use `cpanp` because it allows for installing Perl modules as system packages. Since this module is relatively small, I can probably just copy it into my project, at least until I get rid of it in the code ;)